# Maintenance plan run date wrong

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2017, jobs, maintenance-plans

Win server 2019 & SQL Server 2017

On Jan 28th, 2022, I setup 3 maintenance plans to backup 3 databases from 3:00AM – 3:40AM. The last one finishes at 3:45AM. For a few weeks I confirmed that I am getting backups every day and then did not check till today **03/17/2022 at about 12:00PM**

Today I happen to notice that the most recent backups of all the databases were dated **03/16/2022.** Both in the backup name as well as Windows File stamp.

03/16/2022 03:44 AM             2,383 Daily_DBNAME_Subplan_1_20220316034417.txt

I then checked the maintenance plan history for each job and not one job was missed or reported a failure since inception, but in each case the most recent job reported had the previous days’ date.

3/16/2022 3:44      Success Daily_DBNAME    Subplan_1

I found an unrelated post, wherein the sysadmin had changed the date (month) incorrectly and now all jobs were scheduled to next run a month later. In this case the Dbadmin resolved it by changing the create date to the next run date.  But in his case the jobs had stopped running. In my case jobs are running, just showing yesterday's date.

After changing the job create date to 03/18/2022. The following is the result of a query on all jobs. Will update on results.

Daily_DBNAME1.Subplan_1 Daily   Every Day 3:00:00 3/18/2022 3:00

Daily_DBNAME2.Subplan_1 Daily   Every Day 3:20:00 3/18/2022 3:20

Daily_DBNAME3.Subplan_1 Daily   Every Day 3:40:00 3/18/2022 3:40

Does anybody know why?

Comment: No luck the jobs did not run this morning. They are now scheduled to run tomorrow.

Comment: Did you consider using Ola Hallengren's maintenance procedures instead of maintenance plans? I don't think maint plans gets much  dev work (nowadays), considering it is mainly an "on premise" feature, and this seem to be a difficult thing to define a repro for...

Comment: Since the jobs did not run on 3/18/2022, I ran them manually. The next run date on the jobs was 03/19/2022.  I did not modify the jobs. This morning the jobs ran as per schedule with today’s date 03/19/2022.

Maybe if I set the create date as 03/17/2022, it would have run on the 18th. I kinda sorta get the logic, but I am not going to mess with it to find out.

Comment: Tibor Karaszi , Perhaps I am mistaken, but I am doing a simple backup of3 DB's and it works. My issue is with the date and time stamp. I suspect at the end of the day these procedures by Ola Hallengren , still need to be scheduled.

Nevertheless , I was not aware of Ola Hallengren,  these are great  tools to have for an amateur ( at best ) DBA & I thank you for directing me to this website.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the whole scenario. You have a maint plan, (which is an SSIS package). This is the one that created your backup file and generate the file name. You also have an Agent, which starts the SSIS package, at whatever time you defines. The question is if the issue is in the SSIS package or the Agent job? I.e., is the jonb started at the right time (see jobhistory)? If so, and it is the file name that is the problem, then you have an issue in the maint plan. And using some alternative solution (Ola's scripts) will solve your case.

Comment: On 1/28 at 8pm I created a maintenance plan to backup a DB at 3:00AM, so effectively next run is the next morning. Checked next day and saw backup created, did not pay attention to date stamp. Since then, the job has successfully run every day without skipping a day. On 03/17, I noticed that the date stamp for most recent job was 03/16. Job history also says 3/16 but not one day was missed since 01/28. I can only presume that the job was running every day and the time stamp was wrong. 

I am not using any 3rd party agent, it is my understanding that the SQL Agent runs scheduled jobs.

Comment: If you are saying that the backup was skipped one day, then likely Agent wasn't running at that time. If you are saying that the file name of the backup file doesn't match the timestamp of the backup file (i.e., the job *was* executed), then there's an issue in the SSIS package (bug in the maint plan).